# unable to play video from sd card after encryption

Tags: android, encryption

I am making a secure video playing app with encryption.In my app encryption done perfectly but it does not play in my VideoView. No error shown.I want when I click that button the video will encrypt and save in storage and play without save decrypted file. But I am unable to do that.Please help me.Tell me where are problem in my code. Thanks

**This is my java code**

```
        encryptButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.vwVideo);
        mVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        encryptButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {
                    encrypt();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Encryption complete ",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        File file = new File(
                Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES),
                "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/encrypt.mp4");

        mVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        try {
            mServer = new LocalSingleHttpServer();
            mServer.setCipher(myGetCipher());
            mServer.start();
            String path = mServer.getURL(file.getPath());
            mVideoView.setVideoPath(path);
            mVideoView.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private Cipher myGetCipher() throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException, InvalidKeyException {
        // avoid the default security provider "AndroidOpenSSL" in Android 4.3+ (http://libeasy.alwaysdata.net/network/#provider)
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("ARC4", "BC");
        c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec("BrianIsInTheKitchen".getBytes(), "ARC4"));
        return c;
    }

    public static void encrypt() throws Exception {
        final byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
        final Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTR/NoPadding");
        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec("1234567890123456".getBytes(), "AES"), new IvParameterSpec(new byte[16]));
        final InputStream is = new FileInputStream("/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/VID_20140217_144346.mp4");
        final OutputStream os = new CipherOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/encrypt.mp4"), c);
        while (true) {
            int n = is.read(buf);
            if (n == -1) break;
            os.write(buf, 0, n);
        }
        os.close();
        is.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        mServer.stop();
    }
```

Comment: You cannot play an encrypted file. You do not seem to be decrypting it anywhere.

Comment: I am very new in android.I think Decrypt algorithm is different.please tell me what should I do?

Comment: I would suggest read a bit more because at the moment the code is very confusing and is very hard to help. From a quick glance, the encryption should be fine. The rest needs more work. You should decrypt the file before playing, and also probably not treat it as a video over HTTP. `myGetCipher()` seems to not be doing much. Probably you wanted to do something else instead? Decrypt for example?

Comment: I Already decrypt file for an other app but that decryption file save in sd card but don't want that for this case.

Comment: File decfile = new File("/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/decrypt.mp4");
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outfile);
FileInputStream encfis = new FileInputStream(outfile);
FileOutputStream decfos = new FileOutputStream(decfile);
Cipher decipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();encipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skey);CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(fis,encipher);decipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skey);CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(decfos,decipher);

Comment: this above code decrypt and save that in sd card.

Comment: The code in the question does not look like this. Maybe you did not move it correctly between the two projects?

Comment: same project but different part.this part for save decrypt file and main question is directly play without save decrypt file.I understand that the decrypt process is the main problem. [link](http://libeasy.alwaysdata.net/network/#faq)reference..check this

Comment: The decryption must take place before playing. The video will be stored at least in memory, without encryption. If the video is large enough, there will not be enough memory and the application will crash. Is there a reason you do not want to store it in the SD card? Anyway, you are already taking it from the SD card prior to encryption.